# What do you call a person who values experiences over possessions (material things)?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a person who values novel experiences over possessions (material things)?
Example: Nomads are the kind of people that fit in this category.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The duplicate you indicate does not cover the valuing of novel experiences.

Comment: I agree that just because someone doesn't value *possessions* doesn't mean what they *do* value is ***novel** experiences*. But is that a useful sub-category anyway? What about people who only specifically value ***enjoyable** experiences* (hedonists)? Or only value ***enlightening** experiences* (seekers after knowledge / truth)? I kinda doubt OP is specifically looking for ***thrill-seekers***, but that's about the only thing I can clearly associate with seeking ***novel*** experiences.

Comment: Casually speaking, I'm looking for a word that describes a person who prefers having new experiences over possessing materialistic things for happiness.

Comment: There's the term "neophile", which describes someone who is attracted to novelty, but it doesn't particularly imply new experiences as opposed to new possessions.

Comment: @GorvGoyl Why, please? How in English or any language are the two to be compared? Is there a scale of happiness sliding between 'new experiences' and 'possessing material things'?

Quite separately, how are you equating 'materialistic' with 'material'?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest the relatively new concept of [sensation-seekers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensation_seeking).

> a personality trait defined by the search for experiences and feelings, that are "varied, novel, complex and intense", and by the readiness to "take physical, social, legal, and financial risks for the sake of such experiences." Risk is not an essential part of the trait, as many activities associated with it are not risky. However, risk may be ignored, tolerated, or minimized and may even be considered to add to the excitement of the activity.

Answer (score 0):

*Materialist* is a common word for the opposite person and you gave the nomad example, so I suggest *nonmaterialist* or *unmaterialist* in which the productive prefixes *non-* and *un-* are used. The adjective *nonmaterialistic* is more common to describe a nonmaterialistic lifestyle.

[*Collins*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/materialist) defines a *materialist* as:

> A materialist is someone who attaches a lot of importance to money and wants to possess a lot of material things.

<sub>Note: Not to be confused with *materialism* (also called *physicalism*) in philosophy. In summary, it is a philosophical theory that everything exists is material.</sub>

A more precise word, as a neologism, that came to my mind is *experiencist*, and *experiencism* for the mindset. There are online results with these words per google search with some other meanings too; and someone coined them before with the intended meaning also.

> Materialism is defined as preoccupation with or emphasis on material objects and consideration with a disinterest or rejection of spiritual, intellectual, or cultural values. I hereby coin the word **“experiencism”** as a similar obsession with experiences, bought or otherwise. Just as a **materialist** brags about possessing an exclusive piece of furniture, we **experiencists** will make a big deal out of the experience of having an exclusive access to an artist. 
> <sub>[*aboghani.medium.com*](https://aboghani.medium.com/experiencism-ccbd7c95daef)</sub>

There are words for someone who enjoys life like *bon vivant* but it is too general and it can mean someone who enjoys luxurious things in life, or good food and drink; and it can have the connotations of a materialist. There is the word *hedonist* for someone who is devoted to the pursuit of pleasure, a pleasure-seeker; but the word is too strong and a hedonist can still have a materalistic lifestyle. An *ascetic* is a person who abstains from wordly pleasures or denies material satisfaction; but it is mainly for religious purposes.

Comment: "[materialism/materialist](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/materialist)" can refer to hedonism and a desire for physical gratification, so it could include the desire for hedonistic experiences.

Comment: @StuartF Yes, I've mentioned something similar in the last paragraph. Although, my first suggestion is the opposite of a materialist: a _nonmaterialist_ or an _unmaterialist_. I've provided _materialist_ as a contrast in the explanation as it is a more common word. I'm not quite sure if your comment is a disagreement with my answer or if you have fully read my answer.